# openvpn при подключении отправить почту

Tags: debian, email, openvpn

Добрый день.
Есть файл /var/run/openvpn-status.log в который попадают уведомления о подключении, обновляется раз в минуту:

пример: 192.168.*.*,user,*.*.*.*:*,Thu Nov 24 13:00:18 2016

помогите, пожалуйста, написать скриптик, который бы все время парсил этот файлик и (например как в примере user) отправлял на почту уведомление (var/mail/user2)
пользователей несколько штук.

мой скудный нерабочий пример:
tail -f /var/run/openvpn-status.log | grep user | echo «$user connected» | mail -s «$user connected» user2

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/28733/416190 http://serverfault.com/q/528568/292034

Answer (score 3):

Может я чего-то не понимаю, но зачем парсить какой-то лог, когда можно почитать руководство прямо на сайте разработчика?

Из https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage

> --client-connect cmd Run command cmd on client connection. cmd consists of a path to script (or executable program), optionally
>   followed by arguments. The path and arguments may be single- or
>   double-quoted and/or escaped using a backslash, and should be
>   separated by one or more spaces.
>
> The command is passed the common name and IP address of the
>   just-authenticated client as environmental variables (see
>   environmental variable section below). The command is also passed the
>   pathname of a freshly created temporary file as the last argument
>   (after any arguments specified in cmd ), to be used by the command to
>   pass dynamically generated config file directives back to OpenVPN.
>
> If the script wants to generate a dynamic config file to be applied on
>   the server when the client connects, it should write it to the file
>   named by the last argument.
>
> See the --client-config-dir option below for options which can be
>   legally used in a dynamically generated config file.
>
> Note that the return value of script is significant. If script returns
>   a non-zero error status, it will cause the client to be disconnected.
>
> --client-disconnect cmd Like --client-connect but called on client instance shutdown. Will not be called unless the --client-connect
>   script and plugins (if defined) were previously called on this
>   instance with successful (0) status returns. The exception to this
>   rule is if the --client-disconnect command or plugins are cascaded,
>   and at least one client-connect function succeeded, then ALL of the
>   client-disconnect functions for scripts and plugins will be called on
>   client instance object deletion, even in cases where some of the
>   related client-connect functions returned an error status.
>
> The --client-disconnect command is passed the same pathname as the
>   corresponding --client-connect command as its last argument. (after
>   any arguments specified in cmd ).

Comment: клиентские конфиги не могу править, только на стороне сервера

Comment: ну это же в серверном конфиге